# Functions only returns else condition but not if

Tags: python

I am making a rock paper scissors program in python.

I have written a function which should return the result of a game but it only returns the else condition, what do?

Here is the code of the program.

```
import random

def emove():
    computer=["r","p","s"]
    return(random.choice(computer))

def winner():
    if user == "r" and emove == "p":
        return("Computer won!")
    elif user  == "p" and emove == "r":
        return("You won!")
    elif user  == "p" and emove == "s":
        return("Computer won!")
    elif user  == "s" and emove == "p":
        return("You won!")
    elif user  == "r" and emove == "s":
        return("You won!")
    elif user  == "s" and emove == "p":
        return("You won!")
    elif user  == emove:
        return("Tie")
    else:
        return("Wrong input")

user=input("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors, to play enter the initial letter of the choice you make:").lower()
while user:
    print("Computer chose",emove(),",you chose", (user), winner() )
    
    playagain = input("Play again? (y/n): ").lower()
    if playagain =="n":
        print("Thanks for playing")
        break
```

Comment: In `emove == "p"`, `emove` is the function `emove` defined above

Comment: `emove` is a function, `emove == "some string"` is always false. You need to assign the return of emove to a variable and pass that as an arg to winner.

Answer (score 2):

`emove` is a function , so `emove == "p"` always return `Flase`

So I suggest you the following minor changes:

```
import random
    
def emove():
    computer=["r","p","s"]
    return(random.choice(computer))

def winner():
    if user == "r" and em == "p":
        return("Computer won!")
    elif user  == "p" and em == "r":
        return("You won!")
    elif user  == "p" and em == "s":
        return("Computer won!")
    elif user  == "s" and em == "p":
        return("You won!")
    elif user  == "r" and em == "s":
        return("You won!")
    elif user  == "s" and em == "p":
        return("You won!")
    elif user  == em:
        return("Tie")
    else:
        return("Wrong input")

user=input("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors, to play enter the initial letter of the choice you make:").lower()
while user:
    em=emove()
    print("Computer chose",em,",you chose", (user), winner() )
    
    playagain = input("Play again? (y/n): ").lower()
    if playagain =="n":
        print("Thanks for playing")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are missing function parantheses `emove()` inside `winner()` function.

```
  def winner():
    print(user,emove())
    var = emove() # storing random choice in variable.
    if user == "r" and var == "p":
        return ("Computer won!")
    elif user == "p" and var == "r":
        return ("You won!")
    elif user == "p" and var == "s":
        return ("Computer won!")
    elif user == "s" and var == "p":
        return ("You won!")
    elif user == "r" and var == "s":
        return ("You won!")
    elif user == "s" and var == "p":
        return ("You won!")
    elif user == var:
        return ("Tie")
    else:
        return ("Wrong input")
```

Comment: Your answer could use a bit of improvement as there is still a potential bug: look at what the `emove()` function does - it generates a random return value every time it is called. So, if you call it for every condition check, this code could still always go to `else` clause.

Comment: `user == "s" and var == "p"` branch is tested twice. I think you meant `user == "s" and var == "r":`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost right, but you have a few things wrong with your implementation.  Here is a version of your code that I think does everything you desire:

```
import random

def computer_move():
    computer = ["r", "p", "s"]
    return (random.choice(computer))

def winner(emove):
    if user == "r" and emove == "p":
        return ("Computer won!")
    elif user == "p" and emove == "r":
        return ("You won!")
    elif user == "p" and emove == "s":
        return ("Computer won!")
    elif user == "s" and emove == "p":
        return ("You won!")
    elif user == "r" and emove == "s":
        return ("You won!")
    elif user == "s" and emove == "p":
        return ("You won!")
    elif user == emove:
        return ("Tie")
    else:
        return ("Wrong input")

while True:    
    user = input("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors, to play enter the initial letter of the choice you make:").lower()
    emove = computer_move()
    print("Computer chose", emove, ",you chose", user, winner(emove))
    playagain = input("Play again? (y/n): ").lower()
    if playagain == "n":
        print("Thanks for playing")
        break
```

Comment: In this version, computer will stick to the same move forever, shouldn't `emove = computer_move()` be inside the loop?

Comment: DOH!  You're right!  Fixed that.  Thanks for that heads up